# How to sort this datset to create a proper dataframe

Tags: r

Here is a smaple of data set:

```html
df<-read.table (text="Id    Name    Surname Group   A1  A2  A3  Type1   Gen1    B1  B2  B3  Type2   Gen2
116 Matt    Dabi    A   4   4   4   AB  N   3   3   4   G   N
116 Matt    Dabi    D   4   3   2   D   N   4   3   2   G   N
116 Matt    Dabi    Q   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
116 Matt    Dabi    B   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
", header=TRUE)
```

```html
Id  Name    Surname Group   A1  A2  A3  Type1   Gen1
116 Matt    Dabi    A   4   4   4   AB  N
116 Matt    Dabi    D   4   3   2   D   N
116 Matt    Dabi    Q   3   3   4   G   N
116 Matt    Dabi    B   4   3   2   G   N
```

I have tried df %>% na.omit()

Comment: A1: B3 for this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With multiple patterns, one option is to create a `spec` with `build_longer_spec` and then use `pivot_longer_spec`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
spec <- df %>% 
    build_longer_spec(cols = matches("^[A-Za-z]+\\d+$"), 
    names_to = ".value", names_pattern = ".*(\\d+)")  %>% 
    mutate(`.value` = case_when(str_detect(`.name`, "^[AB]\\d+$") ~ 
        str_c('A', `.value`), 
       str_detect(`.name`, 'Type') ~ 'Type1',
         str_detect(`.name`, 'Gen') ~ 'Gen1')) 
pivot_longer_spec(df, spec, values_drop_na = TRUE)
# A tibble: 4 × 9
     Id Name  Surname Group    A1    A2    A3 Type1 Gen1 
  <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
1   116 Matt  Dabi    A         4     4     4 AB    N    
2   116 Matt  Dabi    A         3     3     4 G     N    
3   116 Matt  Dabi    D         4     3     2 D     N    
4   116 Matt  Dabi    D         4     3     2 G     N
```

Comment: @user330 I was using the example from the other post.  I believe you have columns until B3, then change the code from `A1:C3` to `A1:B3`

Comment: @user330 is it the same data in your post?  which is working fine.  From the comments, the formatting is changed.  Can you update your post with the same code

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: @user330 your updated data gives `> str(df)
'data.frame': 0 obs. of  70 variables:`

Comment: Sorry, Please check now

Comment: @user330 your updated post have multiple pattern i..e for the columns A1, B1, etc.  the endd result is A1, and corresponding A2, .. where as the Type and Gen, it is slightly different.  The update in my solution may help

Answer (score 3):

Here another approach using `pivot_wider`:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with(c("A", "B")), names_to="ID") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(ID=sub("B", "A", ID)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(ID))
```

In case of more columns, one can use:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(matches("[A-Z][1-9]"), names_to="ID") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(ID = sub("[B-Z]", "A", ID)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID)
```

given that the rows are uniquely identified otherwise.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
     Id Name  Surname Group    A1    A2    A3
  <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1   116 Matt  Dabi    A         4     4     4
2   116 Matt  Dabi    D         4     3     2
3   116 Matt  Dabi    Q         4     3     3
4   116 Matt  Dabi    B         4     2     4
```

Comment: You are right. This is a nice puzzle or some kind of poking in the fog where we get another piece of information with each edit. (;

Comment: So we need to have 4 rows

Comment: i get this error Error: Can't combine `A1` <integer> and `Type1` <character>

Comment: The data structure posted in the comment differs from the original data structure. SO is no chat platform, so please try to adapt the answers to your needs. Then, if you get stuck or need further extensions, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `tidyr::pivot_longer` like so:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(matches("^[A-Z]\\d$"), names_to = c("set", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.)(\\d)$", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  select(-set) %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~ paste0("A", .x), .cols = matches("^\\d"))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>      Id Name  Surname Group    A1    A2    A3
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1   116 Matt  Dabi    A         4     4     4
#> 2   116 Matt  Dabi    D         4     3     2
#> 3   116 Matt  Dabi    Q         4     3     3
#> 4   116 Matt  Dabi    B         4     2     4
#> 5   116 Matt  Dabi    Q         4     3     3
#> 6   116 Matt  Dabi    B         4     2     4
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L), Name = c(
  "Matt",
  "Matt", "Matt", "Matt", "Matt", "Matt"
), Surname = c(
  "Dabi",
  "Dabi", "Dabi", "Dabi", "Dabi", "Dabi"
), Group = c(
  "A", "D",
  "Q", "B", "Q", "B"
), A1 = c(4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA), A2 = c(
  4L,
  3L, NA, NA, NA, NA
), A3 = c(4L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), B1 = c(
  NA,
  NA, 4L, 4L, NA, NA
), B2 = c(NA, NA, 3L, 2L, NA, NA), B3 = c(
  NA,
  NA, 3L, 4L, NA, NA
), C1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 4L), C2 = c(
  NA,
  NA, NA, NA, 3L, 2L
), C3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -6L
))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work if I want to continue C1, D1, E1, F1, G1..... Can we do better

Comment: @user330 I just made an edit. Added some groups C1, C2, C3 and slightly adjusted my code. As long as this patterns repeats in your data it should work for more general cases.

Comment: Thanks, when I add C1 C2 C3 D1 D2 D3... I get this error:Error: Can't combine `A1` <integer> and `Type1` <character>. I think your datset doe not relect my data set, it shoul have only 3 rows.

Comment: The question of the OP is a nice puzzle, but in practice I would suggest to just transform the table with `pivot_longer` and not to convert the A1:A3 into columns.

Comment: @user330 Try with `pivot_longer(matches("^[A-Z]\\d$"), names_to = c("set", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.)(\\d)$", values_drop_na = TRUE)`. As I wasn't aware of `Type1` my regex was a bit too sloppy to account for that.